# Mono Runtime need to be bundled with Mono Winform app for Mac

Tags: macos, mono, runtime, mkbundle

I am new to development on Mac.

I migrated one Windows Form App that I have created using C# on Windows platform. I am able to run this app on Mac inside MonoDevelop and run inside IDE without problem.

Now, I like to create setup that will include Mono Runtime with my application so my application can continue to run if user has mono runtime installed or not.

My mac machine has Mac OS X 10.5. I have installed the latest Mono Develop tools and Mono runtime 2.0. That's all I have done.

I have been using MkBundle tool to create the bundle to achieve this. My command looks something like this on terminal:

mkbundle -o hello hello.exe --deps

I am getting following error when I run this command.
"sh: as: command not found".

Error occurs after following text I see on Terminal

"Compiling: 
as -o temp.o temp.s".

Now, i am not sure why I am getting this error.

I am new to Mac/Unix so please provide any instructions that I can easily follow.

Any specific answer or tip in the right directions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Xcode in order for Mkbundle to work. For MacOS 10.5, it used to be a large download from Apple. Starting with MacOS Lion, (10.7,) Xcode comes from the App store. I don't know if MacOS 10.5 can run newer versions of XCode.

[This post talks about where to get old versions of XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839526/where-to-download-older-xcode-versions).

MacOS 10.5 is very old. You might find out that, for one reason or another, you just won't be able to get all of the modern tools you need to run on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

`as` is the (native) assembler and is required by `mkbundle`.

```
$ as -version
Apple Inc version cctools-809~2, GNU assembler version 1.38
```

I don't recall if it's part of the *stock* OSX or if you have to install **Xcode** to get it.

Comment: @poupou..you are right I think that looks like problem based on some other posts.Sorry for basic questions I did install the Xcode but it looks like some GUI tool and it didn't do anything. I don't know what else to do so native assembler will be installed and available to Mkbundle ?

Comment: @user1156494 recent Xcode downloads are an installer. This installer should ask you if you want to install common Unix tools. That's where `as` will be located (if provided by Xcode). Try doing a `find / -name as` in a terminal window to see if it got installed somewhere.